# Delete any cert of certmgr without FriendlyName or <None>

Tags: c#, cert

I I'm having trouble making a filter that deletes any cert that doesn't have firendlyname from my certificate store in general.

Im using c# console.

I tried that but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Still not doing anything about what I want, does anyone have a solution, thank you.

````
private static void RemoveUnwantedCert()
    {
        // Open the Root store
        string RootStoreName = "Root";
        StoreLocation RootStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
        X509Store RootStore = new X509Store(RootStoreName, RootStoreLocation);
        RootStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        // Get all certificates in the Root store
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = RootStore.Certificates;

        // Loop through all the certificates in the Root store
        foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in certificates)
        {
            if (certificate.FriendlyName == "None")

                try
                {
                    // Open the Root store again, this time with ReadWrite permissions
                    RootStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                    // Remove the certificate from the Root store
                    RootStore.Remove(certificate);
                    // Close the Root store
                    RootStore.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            // Break out of the loop
            break;

        }

        // Close the Root store
        RootStore.Close();
        
```
`

I tried that but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Still not doing anything about what I want, does anyone have a solution, thank you.
````

Comment: The break statement at the end of the loop will cause the loop to exit after the first iteration, regardless of whether the certificate was successfully removed or not. This means that only the first certificate with a friendly name of "None" will be deleted. If you want to delete all such certificates, you should remove the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a certificate and all certificates in the chain -

```
   X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "yoursubjectname", false);
    
      var chain = new X509Chain();
      chain.Build(col[0]);
      var allCertsInChain = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    
      foreach (var entry in chain.ChainElements)
      {
        allCertsInChain.Add(entry.Certificate);
      }
    
      store.RemoveRange(allCertsInChain);
```

Comment: Thanks but i just want delete a specified one.

Comment: In this example, you find the certificate by name, take the first [0] and build its chain

Comment: .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "yoursubjectname", false)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but i just want delete a specified one.

Comment: you can make comments to answers.